# How can I make sure Ruby's Find module will always return absolute paths?

Tags: ruby, find

If I run the `Find` module with a relative directory as a parameter, the files returned by it will be relative ones. Can I do anything to make sure I always have absolute paths ?

```
require "find"

Find.find(dir) do |file|
  # do I need to make it absolute myself? will File#extend_path be enough?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, expand_path will do it.

```
require 'find'
Find.find(dir) {|file| puts File.expand_path(file)}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'find'
Find.find(File.expand_path(dir))
```

also seems to work.

Comment: This is actually better than my solution, since it only calls expand_path once, as opposed to once per file.